# How can I use AWK to break line content into multiple lines using a separator

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

Given an input like this:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
```

I would like to get an output like this

```
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

How can I do this with awk?

Comment: how "like that" is your actual data? Because if there are multiple lines of input, you'll have more trouble distinguishing records afterwards (if that's even a problem).

Comment: Does any field contain embedded commas?

Comment: No embedded commas.
Source file will have multiple lines but i mean to obtain just one before applying this parse

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic Awk way of doing this would probably be

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\n"} {$1=$1} 1'
```

or equivalently

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' FS=, OFS='\n'
```

The `{$1=$1}` just forces re-evaluation of the record with the new separator `OFS`, and the `1` triggers the default `print` action. You can use other expressions, such as `NF += 0`, to force the re-evaluation if you prefer - it's a matter of preference.

A quick'n'dirty way would be

```
awk -vRS=, 1
```

(or `awk 1 RS=,`) which treats each comma-separated word as a whole record and outputs them with the default newline record separator.

Comment: The quick'n'dirty way only works if lines ALWAYS have a comma.  If a line doesn't have a comma, a blank line is added to the stream.

Answer (score 3):

Use [tr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) to translate the comma to a newline:

```
echo "field1,field2,field3,field4" | tr "," "\n"
```

This is likely faster than using `awk`, though if you insist, you could do:

```
echo "field1,field2,field3,field4" | awk '{gsub(",","\n");print}'
```

From the [GNU awk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

> gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])
>
> Search target for all of the longest, leftmost, nonoverlapping matching substrings it can find and replace them with replacement. The ‘g’ in gsub() stands for “global,” which means replace everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, the tr solution is just what i needed

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash` and `csvformat` from the [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) collection to change the field delimiter from a comma to a newline:

```
$ csvformat -D $'\n' file
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

This is assuming that the input in `file` is properly formatted CSV.  This would also properly handle embedded commas:

```
$ cat file
"field,1",field2,field3,field4
$ csvformat -D $'\n' file
field,1
field2
field3
field4
```